# How to access sockets from lua in nginx?

Tags: sockets, nginx, lua

I've built nginx from sources with lua support and I'm able to run server-side scripts like this:

```
http {
  lua_package_path '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/?.lua;;';
  server {
    listen 80;    
    location /hi {
        content_by_lua '            
            ngx.header["Content-Type"] = "text/plain;charset=utf-8"
            ngx.say("Hello world!")
            --local s = require("socket")
            ngx.say(_VERSION);
        ';
    }
  }
}
```

So when I access http://localhost/hi, I get this output:

```
Hello world!
Lua 5.1
```

If I uncomment line **local s = require("socket")** then I get following error in my browser:

```
Unable to load page
Problem occurred while loading the URL http://localhost/hi
Connection terminated unexpectedly
```

soucket.lua presents in this folder:

```
root@debian:/usr/local/share/lua/5.1# ls
ltn12.lua  mime.lua  socket  socket.lua
```

UPDATE: adding cpath doesn't help:

```
lua_package_cpath '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/?.so;/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/socket/?.so;;';

# ls /usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/socket/*.so
/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/socket/core.so  /usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/socket/serial.so  /usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/socket/unix.so

# ls /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/
ltn12.lua  mime.lua  socket  socket.lua
```

How can I fix/diagnose this problem? 
Thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the socket.lua is the [diegonehab/luasocket](https://github.com/diegonehab/luasocket),
then it requires socket/core.so

You need to specify the **lua_package_cpath**

cpath is for compiled shared library modules (.so), path is for text modules (.lua)

/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/?.so - most common value for cpath

Answer (score 2):

Do not try to use LuaSocket inside nginx. LuaSocket is a blocking library and nginx is non-blocking so you will have problems. Check out [ngx.socket.tcp](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxsockettcp) instead. Its API is compatible with `socket.tcp` but it is non-blocking.

Comment: liar =) it goes nonblock mode before connect, also it has methods to set O_NONBLOCK. check the src/usocket.c:371 and src/inet.c:421

Comment: @marsgpl Sure, you can write non-blocking code using LuaSocket with some effort, I should have said "most of the API is blocking by default". The cosocket API is designed so that code looks like "normal" (blocking) LuaSocket code but is actually non-blocking. Also, it does not require an extra module because it is native to the Lua nginx module.

Comment: @catwell In many cases actually you cannot access LuaSocket like in init_worker_by_lua*, in those cases, you have to be independent to ngx.socket.